# VS Code, find/replace access find results in the replace field

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have phone numbers on my file and I would like to surround each of them with braces, so if I have this:

```
"+49-1111"
"+49-2222"
```

I would like to run a replace operation and to get this:

```
["+49-1111"]
["+49-2222"]
```

Is that possible with the current vs code find/replace action?
If it is a dup sorry but I could find any explanation anywhere.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more relevant to regular expression.

Find `("\+\d{2}-\d{4}")`, replace the occurrences with `[$1]`

Be sure to turn the "Use Regular Expression" switch on.

Comment: Thanks! I highlighted in your answer things I thought were of extra importance :)